# Is it possible to solve $(x+1)^x = x^{x+1}$ for $x$ in a closed form?

Tags: calculus, special-functions

Is it possible to solve for $x$ in a closed form?

$$(x+1)^x = x^{x+1}$$

Inspiration is simply because my kid asked if it is possible to solve. We used Desmos to solve for it graphically. He has tried for a few days to solve algebraically. Wonder if there is any way to get to a closed-form solution?

Comment: It seems unlikely there is a good closed formula, even using the Lambert $W$ function.

Comment: Why not tell us what Desmos gave you as an approximate answer?

Comment: [More info here](https://oeis.org/A085846).

Comment: Iteration of $x \mapsto \left(1+\frac1x\right)^x$ gives $x \approx 2.2932$ very quickly. The function is pretty well-behaved in that neighborhood.

Comment: This probably isn’t solvable, but if you change it to $+2$, it happens to have a nice solution: $(2+2)^2=2^{2+2}$

Comment: Incidentally, not sure what tag this question falls under, but it's probably not `number-theory`.

Comment: The amount of variables/power towers make it difficult to isolate, using a series/integral. It is similar to the [Foias constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FoiasConstant.html)

Comment: @BrianTung :  I added special-functions in case somebody knows one (like the Lambert W function, although not that one) that helps here.

Comment: This question has been asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2148897/any-recommendations-on-how-to-solve-this-using-a-power-series-xx-1-x?noredirect=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2968919/when-does-xx1-x1x?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 2):

$$(x+1)^x=x^{x+1}$$

Because this is not so obvious, we first want to show that the terms $(x+1)^x$ and $x^{x+1}$ are algebraically independent.

Let $x$ be a real number:
$$(x+1)^\frac{x}{x+1}=x$$

Let $x$ be an algebraic irrational real number $a$:
$$(a+1)^\frac{a}{a+1}=a\tag{1}$$
On the left-hand side of equation 1:
Because $a$ is algebraic irrational, $\frac{a}{a+1}$ is algebraic irrational.
Because the base $(a+1)$ is algebraic and not in $\{0,1\}$, and its exponent $\frac{a}{a+1}$ is algebraic irrational, [Gelfond–Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) implies that $(a+1)^\frac{a}{a+1}$ is transcendental.
But the right-hand side of equation 1, $a$, is algebraic. Therefore the terms $(x+1)^x$ and $x^{x+1}$ are algebraically independent.

$$(x+1)^x-x^{x+1}=0$$

We see, your equation can be rearranged to a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($(x+1)^x,x^{x+1}$) and with no univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to solve the equation by rearranging for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (elementary operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

I don't know if your equation has solutions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

Also, your equation seems not to be in a form that can be solved in terms of Lambert W.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you look for the zero of fuction
$$f(x)=x\log(x+1)-(x+1)\log(x)$$ Just by inspection, the root is slightly large than $2$ since $f(2)=\log \left(\frac{9}{8}\right)$.

Perform $\color{red}{\text{one single}}$ iteration of a Newton-like method of order $n$ starting with $x_0=2$. This gives an $\color{red}{\text{explicit}}$ closed form expression.

Playing with the order of the method
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_{(n)} & \text{method} \\
 2 &  2.275278763 & \text{Newton} \\
 3 &  2.293646382 & \text{Halley} \\
 4 &  2.293128131 & \text{Householder} \\
 5 &  2.293170097 & \text{no name} \\
 6 &  2.293165867 & \text{no name} \\
 7 &  2.293166336 & \text{no name} \\
 8 &  2.293166282 & \text{no name} \\
 9 &  2.293166288 & \text{no name} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: so `no name` are we saying these order's are up for grabs - happy for you to take n = 5 Claude` and I take `n = 6` :)

Comment: @Chinny84. Long time no speak ! Good to see you here. Thanks & cheers :-)